importmap raises "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" with interact.js
I'm trying to import interact.js with an importmap, but I get the error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'interactjs'.

My importmap:
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "interactjs": "https://cdn.interactjs.io/v1.9.20/interactjs/index.js"
        }
    }
</script>

My JavaScript code:
<script type="module">
    import interact from interactjs;

    interact('.item').draggable({
        onmove(event) {
            console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY)
        },
    })
</script>

A normal script src include works without issue.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>
Any ideas?

James provided the correct solution to the issue in a comment:

The examples here have quotes around the from target. eg import thing from 'here'

